# Loop error on Network Analyst (ArcGIS 9.3)

Tags: python, networking

I am making a loop using the Make Service Area Layer tool of Network Analyst but it doesn't work.
I'd like to make 3 different service areas with 3 different points, each point matching to a facility. A facility is the feature class or layer that is the source for the new network locations. These points call "Armor", "Bouguenais" and "Chantrerie".
My impedance attribute is "Minutes_S1"

And here is my code :

```
import arcgisscripting
gp = arcgisscripting.create()
gp.CheckOutExtension("Network")
gp.AddToolbox("C:/Program Files (x86)/ArcGIS/ArcToolbox/Toolboxes/Network Analyst Tools.tbx")
network = "D:/Travaux/NantesMetropole/Traitements/SIG_Final/Modelisation/voiture/Reseau_Voiture_TOP_ND.nd" 
Armor = "D:/Travaux/NantesMetropole/Traitements/SIG_Final/pts_kml/Pt_Ar.shp"
Bouguenais = "D:/Travaux/NantesMetropole/Traitements/SIG_Final/pts_kml/Pt_Boug.shp"
Chantrerie = "D:/Travaux/NantesMetropole/Traitements/SIG_Final/pts_kml/Pt_Chanr.shp"

facilities_points = ["Armor", "Bouguenais", "Chantrerie"]
while 1:
    for i in facilities_points:
        try:
            gp.MakeServiceAreaLayer_na (network, "Service Area_" + i, "Minutes_S1", "TRAVEL_FROM", "10 20 30 40 50", "SIMPLE_POLYS", "MERGE", "DISKS", "NO_LINES", "OVERLAP", "NO_SPLIT", "", "", "ALLOW_UTURNS", "", "TRIM_POLYS", "200 Meters", "NO_LINES_SOURCE_FIELDS")
            gp.AddLocations_na("Service Area_" + i, "Facilities_" + i, i, "", "100 Meters")
            gp.Solve_na ("Service Area_" + i, "HALT")
            gp.CopyFeatures_management("Service Area_" + i + "/Polygons", "D:/Travaux/NantesMetropole/Traitements/SIG_Final/Modelisation/voiture/test_" + i +".shp")
            print "Minutes_S1 done on", i
        except:
             print "Error on", i
    break
```

Actually an error already occurs on line "gp.AddLocations_na" saying :

```
Error on Armor
Error on Bouguenais
Error on Chantrerie
```

I checked the ESRI help but I still don't know how to solve my problem. Can you help me ?

Answer (score 0):

You say gp.AddLocations_na is causing the problem, but its not apparent from your code.  To debug add a raise statement to your except block.  This will tell you which line is causing the error.  You can always remove it when you get the kinks worked out.

It looks like the lone i is the culprit.  You are passing it as a string when it probably should be the feature class variable.  You could use a dictionary to store the names and variables.

```
#store table/feature class names with the variables
facilities_points = {"Armor":Armor, "Bouguenais":Bouguenais, "Chantrerie":Chantrerie}

#note the while loop is superfluous here
while 1:
    for i in facilities_points:
        try:
            gp.MakeServiceAreaLayer_na (network, "Service Area_" + i, "Minutes_S1", "TRAVEL_FROM", "10 20 30 40 50", "SIMPLE_POLYS", "MERGE", "DISKS", "NO_LINES", "OVERLAP", "NO_SPLIT", "", "", "ALLOW_UTURNS", "", "TRIM_POLYS", "200 Meters", "NO_LINES_SOURCE_FIELDS")
            gp.AddLocations_na("Service Area_" + i, "Facilities_" + i, facilities_points[i], "", "100 Meters")
            gp.Solve_na ("Service Area_" + i, "HALT")
            gp.CopyFeatures_management("Service Area_" + i + "/Polygons", "D:/Travaux/NantesMetropole/Traitements/SIG_Final/Modelisation/voiture/test_" + i +".shp")
            print "Minutes_S1 done on", i
        except:
            #this error message tells you nothing about what really happened
            print "Error on", i

            #Raise the full exception to assist with debugging
            #comment it out once the script works
            raise
    break
```

As an aside, although error handling is a good habit, in my opinion it is rarely helpful for this type of scripting.  Unless you are willing to accept a failed geoprocessing function call and continue on it is best to let the script stop in its tracks and return where the error occured.  However, if you had logging implemented to capture tracebacks and where running this as a scheduled task then the except block would be the place to put the log message.

Comment: Hi Tharen ! I just tried your code and it perfectly worked ! Thank you very much for your help !

Comment: Glad to here. Since you are new to SE check out [gis.stackexchange.com](http://gis.stackexchange.com/). There's lots of good help over there for both GIS and Python related questions. Also, it's helpful to accept answers as it helps members gain [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) points and privileges.